# put a 0 after not buying in a quarter in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a base with the variables ID, month (or period) and the incomes of that month. What I need is to put a 1 if the client buys in the next 3 months or a 0 if not, and do it for all ID.
For example, if I am in month 1 and there's a purchase in the next 3 months, then put a 1 in that row for that client.
In the last periods as there will not be 3 months, an NA appears.

```
 df<-tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Month, ~Incomes,
       1L,     1L,    5000L,
       1L,     2L,       0L,
       1L,     3L,       0L,
       1L,     4L,       0L,
       1L,     5L,       0L,
       1L,     6L,       0L,
       1L,     7L,     400L,
       1L,     8L,     300L,
       1L,     9L,       0L,
       1L,    10L,       0L,
       1L,    11L,       0L,
       1L,    12L,       0L,
       1L,    13L,     400L,
       2L,     1L,       0L,
       2L,     2L,     100L,
       2L,     3L,       0L,
       2L,     4L,       0L,
       2L,     5L,       0L,
       2L,     6L,       0L,
       2L,     7L,       0L,
       2L,     8L,    1500L,
       2L,     9L,       0L,
       2L,    10L,       0L,
       2L,    11L,       0L,
       2L,    12L,     100L,
       2L,    13L,     750L,
       3L,     1L,       0L,
       3L,     2L,       0L,
       3L,     3L,       0L,
       3L,     4L,       0L,
       3L,     5L,     700L,
       3L,     6L,     240L,
       3L,     7L,     100L,
       3L,     8L,       0L,
       3L,     9L,       0L,
       3L,    10L,       0L,
       3L,    11L,       0L,
       3L,    12L,     500L,
       3L,    13L,     760L
  )
df<-as.data.frame(df)
#     ID Month Incomes
#      1     1    5000
#      1     2       0
#      1     3       0
#      1     4       0
#      1     5       0
#      1     6       0
#      1     7     400
#      1     8     300
#      1     9       0
#      1    10       0
#      1    11       0
#      1    12       0
#      1    13     400
#      2     1       0
#      2     2     100
#      2     3       0
#      2     4       0
#      2     5       0
#      2     6       0
#      2     7       0
#      2     8    1500
#      2     9       0
#      2    10       0
#      2    11       0
#      2    12     100
#      2    13     750
#      3     1       0
#      3     2       0
#      3     3       0
#      3     4       0
#      3     5     700
#      3     6     240
#      3     7     100
#      3     8       0
#      3     9       0
#      3    10       0
#      3    11       0
#      3    12     500
#      3    13     760
```

What I hope should look like this:

```
dffinal<- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID_RUT, ~Month, ~Incomes, ~Quarter,
       1L,     1L,    5000L,         0L,
       1L,     2L,       0L,         0L,
       1L,     3L,       0L,         0L,
       1L,     4L,       0L,         1L,
       1L,     5L,       0L,         1L,
       1L,     6L,       0L,         1L,
       1L,     7L,     400L,         1L,
       1L,     8L,     300L,         0L,
       1L,     9L,       0L,         0L,
       1L,    10L,       0L,         0L,
       1L,    11L,       0L,         NA,
       1L,    12L,       0L,         NA,
       1L,    13L,     400L,         NA,
       2L,     1L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,     2L,     100L,         0L,
       2L,     3L,       0L,         0L,
       2L,     4L,       0L,         0L,
       2L,     5L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,     6L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,     7L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,     8L,    1500L,         0L,
       2L,     9L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,    10L,       0L,         1L,
       2L,    11L,       0L,         NA,
       2L,    12L,     100L,         NA,
       2L,    13L,     750L,         NA,
       3L,     1L,       0L,         0L,
       3L,     2L,       0L,         1L,
       3L,     3L,       0L,         1L,
       3L,     4L,       0L,         1L,
       3L,     5L,     700L,         1L,
       3L,     6L,     240L,         1L,
       3L,     7L,     100L,         0L,
       3L,     8L,       0L,         0L,
       3L,     9L,       0L,         1L,
       3L,    10L,       0L,         1L,
       3L,    11L,       0L,         NA,
       3L,    12L,     500L,         NA,
       3L,    13L,     760L,         NA
  )

#     ID Month Incomes Quarterly
#      1     1    5000         0
#      1     2       0         0
#      1     3       0         0
#      1     4       0         1
#      1     5       0         1
#      1     6       0         1
#      1     7     400         1
#      1     8     300         0
#      1     9       0         0
#      1    10       0         0
#      1    11       0        NA
#      1    12       0        NA
#      1    13     400        NA
#      2     1       0         1
#      2     2     100         0
#      2     3       0         0
#      2     4       0         0
#      2     5       0         1
#      2     6       0         1
#      2     7       0         1
#      2     8    1500         0
#      2     9       0         1
#      2    10       0         1
#      2    11       0        NA
#      2    12     100        NA
#      2    13     750        NA
#      3     1       0         0
#      3     2       0         1
#      3     3       0         1
#      3     4       0         1
#      3     5     700         1
#      3     6     240         1
#      3     7     100         0
#      3     8       0         0
#      3     9       0         1
#      3    10       0         1
#      3    11       0        NA
#      3    12     500        NA
#      3    13     760        NA
```

Does anyone how to do it? Thanks for your time

Comment: For the 1st row Incomes is 5000, so should that be 1

Comment: @akrun It is considering the next 3 months, not in which you are standing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) rollapply** Roll forward along `Incomes > 0` returning TRUE if any are TRUE and FALSE otherwise.  Convert that to numeric using `+`.  1:3 means use offsets 1, 2, 3 from the current point, i.e. the next three incomes.  Add the `partial=TRUE` argument to `rollapply` if you want to consider the next and next two incomes near the end of each group where there are not three left.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = +rollapply(Incomes > 0, list(1:3), any, fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) SQL** An SQL solution would be:

```
library(sqldf)

over <- "partition by ID rows between 1 following and 3 following"

fn$sqldf("select 
  *, 
  (max(Incomes > 0) over ($over)) + 
    (case when (count(*) over ($over)) = 3 then 0 else Null end) as Quarter
  from df")
```

This can be simplified if it is OK to process elements for which there are fewer than 3 rows following.  `over` is from above:

```
fn$sqldf("select *, (max(Incomes > 0) over ($over)) as Quarter from df")
```

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of `rollapply` - a bit tidier than my solution.

Comment: Have added (2).

Answer (score 3):

A dplyr solution: sum the next three months using `lag` and take the sign of the result.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(quarter = sign(lead(Incomes, 3) + lead(Incomes, 2) + lead(Incomes))) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#>    ID Month Incomes quarter
#> 1   1     1    5000       0
#> 2   1     2       0       0
#> 3   1     3       0       0
#> 4   1     4       0       1
#> 5   1     5       0       1
#> 6   1     6       0       1
#> 7   1     7     400       1
#> 8   1     8     300       0
#> 9   1     9       0       0
#> 10  1    10       0       1
#> 11  1    11       0      NA
#> 12  1    12       0      NA
#> 13  1    13     400      NA
#> 14  2     1       0       1
#> 15  2     2     100       0
#> 16  2     3       0       0
#> 17  2     4       0       0
#> 18  2     5       0       1
#> 19  2     6       0       1
#> 20  2     7       0       1
#> 21  2     8    1500       0
#> 22  2     9       0       1
#> 23  2    10       0       1
#> 24  2    11       0      NA
#> 25  2    12     100      NA
#> 26  2    13     750      NA
#> 27  3     1       0       0
#> 28  3     2       0       1
#> 29  3     3       0       1
#> 30  3     4       0       1
#> 31  3     5     700       1
#> 32  3     6     240       1
#> 33  3     7     100       0
#> 34  3     8       0       0
#> 35  3     9       0       1
#> 36  3    10       0       1
#> 37  3    11       0      NA
#> 38  3    12     500      NA
#> 39  3    13     760      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Quarterly = c(
      sapply(1:(n() - 3), function(x) +any(Incomes[(x + 1):(x + 3)] > 0)),
      rep(NA, 3)
      )
  ) %>% as.data.frame
```

Output:

```
   ID Month Incomes Quarterly
1   1     1    5000         0
2   1     2       0         0
3   1     3       0         0
4   1     4       0         1
5   1     5       0         1
6   1     6       0         1
7   1     7     400         1
8   1     8     300         0
9   1     9       0         0
10  1    10       0         1
11  1    11       0        NA
12  1    12       0        NA
13  1    13     400        NA
14  2     1       0         1
15  2     2     100         0
16  2     3       0         0
17  2     4       0         0
18  2     5       0         1
19  2     6       0         1
20  2     7       0         1
21  2     8    1500         0
22  2     9       0         1
23  2    10       0         1
24  2    11       0        NA
25  2    12     100        NA
26  2    13     750        NA
27  3     1       0         0
28  3     2       0         1
29  3     3       0         1
30  3     4       0         1
31  3     5     700         1
32  3     6     240         1
33  3     7     100         0
34  3     8       0         0
35  3     9       0         1
36  3    10       0         1
37  3    11       0        NA
38  3    12     500        NA
39  3    13     760        NA
```

And a `base` equivalent:

```
transform(df, Quarterly = ave(Incomes, ID, 
                              FUN = function(x) c(
                                sapply(1:(length(x) - 3), function(y) +any(x[(y + 1):(y + 3)] > 0)),
                                rep(NA, 3)
                                )
                              )
          )
```